# Создание графического интерфейса и вывод графиков в Fortran

Tags: интерфейс, fortran

Столкнулся с проблемой изучения возможностей языка Fortran в части создания графического интерфейса. У меня появилась необходимость создания диалоговых окон, элементов интерфейса и т.д. для конечного пользователя на основе программы, которая делает необходимые вычисления (она тоже написана на Fortran).
Пытался найти информацию в интернете, но, к сожалению, она вся очень отрывчата и непоследовательна, мне сложно понять.
Где можно найти последовательно изложенную информацию об этом? Может существует определенная литература?
Я использую Visual Studio 2019 с компилятором Intel.

Comment: https://silverfrost.com/ftn95-help/clearwinp/api/thefortranstdcallstatement.aspx первое что нашлось (гуглить fortran stdcall), ну и бонусом само апи стандартного интерфейса https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/, при желании можно поискать готовое на гитхабе... думаю что найдется не мало чего, а этот совет почти универсален для любого ЯП, под ос Виндоус :)

Comment: https://cyber.dabamos.de/programming/modernfortran/gnuplot.html

Comment: Есть альтернативный подход, графический интерфейс на python, который уже и вызывает вычислительные модули Fortran. Примеры сборки и использования можете посмотреть в документации - Numpy f2py - https://numpy.org/doc/stable/f2py/usage.html . Как вариант быстрого прототипирования - Fortran magic для  IPython/Jupyter Lab/Jupyter Notebook - https://pypi.org/project/fortran-magic/